# How to get image to cover entire UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, size, bounds

I have this code below that places an image on a view. The problem is that creating a fixed height and width does not work when transferring from iPhone to iPad. I would like the code to transfer the entire canvas, not a fixed amounts.

```
@IBOutlet weak var jj: draw!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let image = UIImage(named: "se")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 300)
    jj.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by *transferring from iPhone to iPad* ??

Comment: I mean that if the width is only 300 then when put on the iPad the image won't even cover half of the uiview even though it will cover the entire iPhone view.

Comment: Why don't you use AutoLayout for that ?

Comment: @RiajurRahman don't know how to code that.

Comment: Hi Sam - don't do this. Fixed frame sizes hasn't worked well since there was more than one iOS device size. Use constraint-based layout in interface builder instead - it is actually easier than what you are trying. Just search for "iOS constraint layout tutorial", many are available (including some updated for Swift 4 I notice). Posting the whole process as an answer to this question would be too long. If you insist on not using constraints look into UIView's contentMode instead, but that might limit you to filling screens completely.

Comment: @SamBurns I suggest you take a look into SnapKit :) http://snapkit.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use auto layout to accomplish this task.

```
      let backgroundImage : UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "name-of-image"))
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return image
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpView()
    }

    func setUpView(){
        view.addSubview(backgroundImage)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            backgroundImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            backgroundImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            backgroundImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            backgroundImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
```

Comment: I am having trouble with the    let image = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "name-of-image")) line. Its not the same when I copy it into Xcode.

Comment: If I write let image = UIImageView(image: "photo""). This does not work.

Comment: Between the parenthesis you should write "image literal" and xcode should pop up a dialogue on the image you want to choose or you can just put the name of the image.
 `let image =  UIImageView(image : "Name-of-the-image") `
 `let image =  UIImageView(image : Image Literal) //Write it directly into  `
xcode so it can recognize you are trying to insert an image

Comment: I added a photo to my question. I think what you suggestion is happening its just I don't know how to add the photo. I tried to drag it in.

Answer (score 0):

As you wish to cover your imageView over jj view.
This code will be working fine.

```
@IBOutlet weak var jj: draw!
private var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad((

    self.imageView = UIImageView(image : UIImage(named: ”se”) )
    // set properties blah blah as your code
   // but do not addSubview to Outlet in viewDidLoad
   // they are not initialized yet
}

override func viewWillAppear( _ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);

    // this method can be called multiple times as the view controller presented or dismissed
    // so make sure the imageView is added to superview if it’s not added
    if self.imageView.superview == nil {
        jj.addSubview(imageView);
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
     // layout your responsive code here
     // you wish to cover your image view upon your jj view
     imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: jj.frame.size)
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with the line    self.imageView = UIImageView(named :”se”)

Comment: Why wait until `viewWillAppear` to add the image view as a subview? Why keep changing the image view's frame in `viewDidLayoutSubview`? Either apply constraints or an `autoresizingMask` in `viewDidLoad` and be done.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following, hope it may help you.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad((

self.imageView.layer.contents = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "se");
// In place of #imageLiteral(resourceName: "se"), you can write your image name 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do it in storyboard. using a AutoLayout[image]

So it looks same in every device.
[image: iphone 8 plus]
[image: ipad]